# Firebase pubsub function works in emulator but not returns immediatly in production

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

My scheduled function

```
// TODO;
export const reportUsage =
  fun.pubsub.schedule("0 0 1 * *").onRun(async (context) => {
    functions.logger.debug("Initialising db");
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const users = await db.collection("users").get();
    users.docs.forEach( async (doc) => {
      functions.logger.debug("Got list of users. Looping..");
      const userData = doc.data();
      const SOME_DATA:number = userData["SOME_DATA"];
      functions.logger.debug("got SOME_DATA of this user");
      const SOME_DATAIntPart:number =
       parseInt(SOME_DATA.toFixed(20).split(".")[0]);
      const SOME_DATAFloatPart:number =
       parseFloat("0." + SOME_DATA.toFixed(20).split(".")[1]);
      const subItemId =
       userData["stripeInfo"]["subscription"]["items"]["data"][0]["id"];
      functions.logger.debug("got sub id of this user");
      await stripe.subscriptionItems.createUsageRecord(subItemId, {
        quantity: SOME_DATAIntPart,
        timestamp: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds,
      }, {
        timeout: 60,
        maxNetworkRetries: 5,
      });
      functions.logger.debug("got reported to stripe");
      await doc.ref.update({
        "SOME_DATA": SOME_DATAFloatPart,
      });
      functions.logger.debug("updated SOME_DATA");
      return null;
    });
  });
```

When I run the function manually from Cloud Scheduler, it returns RIGHT before the Stripe call

```
 await stripe.subscriptionItems.createUsageRecord(subItemId, {
        quantity: SOME_DATAIntPart,
        timestamp: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds,
      }, {
        timeout: 60,
        maxNetworkRetries: 5,
      });
```

The logs i'm logging show this
[image: Image showing logs in Google Cloud]

As you can see, it immediately returns before executing the Stripe call.

The errors in the last log are this:
[image: Image showing the error log]

However, running the functions, firestore and pubsub emulator, using the functions shell I can call the reportUsage function and this is what prints out

[image: Image showing working logs in emulator]

Can someone please tell me why the pubsub function is not working in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `async/await` within a `forEach()` loop, see ["JavaScript: async/await with forEach()"](https://codeburst.io/javascript-async-await-with-foreach-b6ba62bbf404) and ["Using async/await with a forEach loop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

You can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as follows:

```
export const reportUsage = fun.pubsub
  .schedule('0 0 1 * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    functions.logger.debug('Initialising db');

    const db = admin.firestore();
    const users = await db.collection('users').get();

    users.docs.forEach((doc) => {
      functions.logger.debug('Got list of users. Looping..');
      const userData = doc.data();
      const SOME_DATA: number = userData['SOME_DATA'];
      functions.logger.debug('got SOME_DATA of this user');
      const SOME_DATAIntPart: number = parseInt(
        SOME_DATA.toFixed(20).split('.')[0]
      );
      const SOME_DATAFloatPart: number = parseFloat(
        '0.' + SOME_DATA.toFixed(20).split('.')[1]
      );
      const subItemId =
        userData['stripeInfo']['subscription']['items']['data'][0]['id'];
      functions.logger.debug('got sub id of this user');

      const promises = [];
      // We push a Promise to the promsies Array. Note that the then() method returns a promise.
      promises.push(
        stripe.subscriptionItems
          .createUsageRecord(
            subItemId,
            {
              quantity: SOME_DATAIntPart,
              timestamp: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds,
            },
            {
              timeout: 60,
              maxNetworkRetries: 5,
            }
          )
          .then(() => {
            return doc.ref.update({
              SOME_DATA: SOME_DATAFloatPart,
            });
          })
      );

      functions.logger.debug('updated SOME_DATA');
    });

    await Promise.all(promises);
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I got another problem now with no detailed logs to fix the problem.
```Function execution took 4366 ms, finished with status: 'error'```

after logging functions.logger.debug('got SOME_DATA of this user');

This might be because some data is NULL in the database, so I will try a bit and come back to you.

Comment: Update: Works great! Thanks a lot!! 

For people looking at this in the future, if there is some NULL data and you need to skip an iteration of the forEach loop, `return` instead of `continue`